# Extracting unique elements from array within different arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, robo3t

I have a collection with this structure:

```
{
    "name": "1",
    "array1": [
        {
            "arrayname1A" : "A",
             "array2": [
                 { "value": "1" },
                 { "value": "3" }
             ]
        },
        {
             "arrayname1B": "B",
             "array2": [
                 { "value": "5" },
             ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "2",
    "array1": [
        {
            "arrayname1A": "A",
            "array2": [
                { "value": "1" },
                { "value": "7" }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I extract the unique "value" from every different array2? The end result I am looking for would be something like `"1","3","5","7"` with no repeated values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the [`distinct()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) method and the [*dot notation*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) to access the "value" field.

```
db.collection.distinct('array1.array2.value')
```

which yields:

```
[ "1", "3", "5", "7" ]
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was searching for :)